# Right way to create contract and flow in Corda

Tags: corda

I am implementing trade finance usecase where numerous participants are involved.

I thought that creating contract between participants(2) makes more sense rather than creating flows for participants(2)

Can you please suggest,
1) Should we create different flows per contract for changing asset ownership OR
2) Should we create different contracts handled by single flow,

Answer (score 0):

Contracts simply indicate which transactions are valid.

Instead, the number of flows you define depends on the number of different ways you want to change asset ownership.

For example, you may define:

- One flow for removing from participant from ownership
- One flow for adding a participant to ownership
- etc.